# asterisk - run a dial plan when a user joins a confbridge

Tags: asterisk

I am using asterisk's confbridge app for a service I am developing. I want to be able to run some dial plan commands when a user joins the conference. How can I do this?

I didn't find a simple answer. Since the confbridge command is synchronous, it only exits when the user hangs up or is kicked from the conference. I also read a little bit about local dialing, I can split the user's channel with a Dial command, one channel will execute the confbridge command and the other one will execute the dial plan I want. The problem is that I don't know how to synchronize them... I want the dialplan code to be executed only after the confbridge command was executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have use AMI with event listeners.

There are no way issue command on same channel(it BLOCKED by conference). But you can use something like chan_spy or enother channel.

You can't split user's channel. You understand something wrong. You can create new channel(independend) and join via chan_spy or conference.

Only way do any response about actions is ami events.